# Can we add add objects to django queryset like we do to python list. I have an empty django queryset, now I want to add objects to it

Tags: python, django

This is how I have initialized an Empty Queryset now I want to add objects to it.
How can I do that.

```
 from django.db.models.query import EmptyQuerySet
```

Answer (score 0):

`EmptyQuerySet` is a class to checking if a queryset is empty by `.none()`

A queryset represents a query you make to your database and it have to be translatable to an SQL query.

So you can't add objects to a QuerySet like to python list but you can combine queryset using set operations.
See [QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#queryset-api-reference) for more information.